# mouseIsOver() is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change margin of one tag when mouse is hovered on its parent.
mouseIsOver() method doesn't making any change.

```
function der(){
    if($(".experience-div li").mouseIsOver()){
        $(".star").css('margin-right','10px');
    }
}
der();
```

I changed it to is() method, still nothing has changed.

>

```
function der(){
    if($(".experience-div li").is(":hover")){
        $(".star").css('margin-right','10px');
    }
}
der();
```

Comment: By far the best way to do this is to use CSS, not JavaScript, assuming there's some kind of relationship between `.star` and the things you're hovering.

Comment: T.J. Crowder-how can I select one element when mouse is hovered over another in CSS?

Comment: It depends on whether there's a relationship between them you can use. Sometimes you can, but if they're completely unrelated, you can't.

Comment: There is a relationship between them

Comment: If you told us what it was, we might be able to help you do this with CSS. (We might not, but...)

Answer (score 1):

There is no `mouseIsOver` function in jQuery or the DOM.

You can use jQuery's [`hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/):

```
function der(){
    $(".experience-div li").hover(
        function() {
            $(".star").css('margin-right','10px');
        },
        function() {
            $(".star").css('margin-right','auto'); // Or whatever it should be when not hovered
        }
    );
}
der();
```

I wouldn't recommend manipulating the style directly like that, though, I'd use a class:

```
function der(){
    $(".experience-div li").hover(
        function() {
            $(".star").addClass('hovered');
        },
        function() {
            $(".star").removeClass('hovered')
        }
    );
}
der();
```

With

```
.star.hovered {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

**Live Example:**

```js
function der() {
  $(".experience-div li").hover(
    function() {
      $(".star").addClass('hovered');
    },
    function() {
      $(".star").removeClass('hovered')
    }
  );
}
der();
```

```css
.star.hovered {
  margin-right: 10px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="star">I'm the star</div>
<div class="experience-div">
  <ul>
    <li>Hover me</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To listen to events (such as mouseover) in jQuery you need to use the `.on` function:

```
$(".experience-div")
  .on('mouseenter', 'li',  function () {
    $(".star").css('margin-right', '10px');
  })
  .on('mouseleave', 'li', function () {
    $(".star").css('margin-right', '0');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use JS to complete this. you simply need to add a :hover state to the class in question.

Comment: That would be true if the OP were changing the style of the element being hovered. They aren't. We haven't seen their structure, so we don't know if there's some kind of sibling or other structural relationship that can be exploited.